# PHP checkbox & radiobuttons

Tags: php, validation, select, radio-button

I'm new to PHP and I'm currently learning while doing a school project.
I have a form with different kinds of fields in it, when user clicks submit they might get all kinds of error messages, they have entered too many characters, not enough etc.

**1)** My first problem is with select menu. I finally got it to give the error message if the user does not choose anything from it. However when the user clicks "submit", the page forgets what he chose. I can't seem to figure it out.

### Here is my HTML:

```
<label>Platform:</label>                    
<select name="platformi" id="platformi">

<option value="-1" <?php if (isset($platformi) && $platformi=="Choose") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Choose</option>
<option value="1"  <?php if (isset($platformi) && $platformi=="PC") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>PC</option>
<option value="2"  <?php if (isset($platformi) && $platformi=="Console") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Console</option>
<option value="3"  <?php if (isset($platformi) && $platformi=="Mobile") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Mobile</option>
</select> <span class="error"><?php print($lisays->getError($platformError));?></span><br>
```

### and here is my PHP:

```
private static $virhelista = array (
    0 => "",
    51 => "You have to choose a platform: PC, console or mobile!",);

        public function checkPlatformi($required = true) { 

            if($_POST['platformi'] == -1)
            return 51;

            else {
            return 0;
            }
        }
```

**2)** My second problem is with radio buttons, I cant find a way to validate them (the user doesn't get an error message when he fails to choose one before submitting). I have tried a lot of different codes.

### Here is my HTML:

```
<label>Pelin tyyppi:</label>
<input type="radio" name="tyyppi" value="t1"> <?php if (isset($tyyppi) && $tyyppi=="fps") echo "checked";?>FPS-Peli
<input type="radio" name="tyyppi" value="t2"> <?php if (isset($tyyppi) && $tyyppi=="rp") echo "checked";?> Roolipeli            
<input type="radio" name="tyyppi" value="t3"> <?php if (isset($tyyppi) && $tyyppi=="adventure") echo "checked";?> Seikkailupeli 
<input type="radio" name="tyyppi" value="t4"> <?php if (isset($tyyppi) && $tyyppi=="strategy") echo "checked";?> Strategiapeli  
<input type="radio" name="tyyppi" value="t5"> <?php if (isset($tyyppi) && $tyyppi=="sports") echo "checked";?> Urheilupeli      
<input type="radio" name="tyyppi" value="t6"> <?php if (isset($tyyppi) && $tyyppi=="simulator") echo "checked";?> Simulaattori
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: it looks like you posting to the same page so it will forget the variables, post to a different page get your post values and put these into sessions then redirect to your input page and check if the sessions is active then your html code

Answer (score 1):

1) In your html you're looking for $platformi which is not set. If you want to keep the choice made by the user you have to allocate it in the answer. You're missing the allocation of this variable in your php:

```
$platformi = $_POST['platformi'];
```

2) If you want a check to be performed before submitting you won't be able to do it with php only as it's running on server side and not on client side, some javascript may help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do small change in your code as follows

```
    <label>Platform:</label>                    
<select name="platformi" id="platformi">

<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="1"  <?= ($platformi=="PC") ? 'selected':'' ?>>PC</option>
<option value="2"  <?= ($platformi=="Console")  ? 'selected':'' ?>>Console</option>
<option value="3"  <?= ( $platformi=="Mobile") ? 'selected':'' ?>>Mobile</option>
</select> <span class="error"><?php print($lisays->getError($platformError));?></span><br>


private static $virhelista = array (
    0 => "",
    51 => "You have to choose a platform: PC, console or mobile!",);

        public function checkPlatformi($required = true) { 
            $platformi = $_POST['platformi'];
            if(empty($platformi) {
                return 51;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

For validation you can use [Bootstrap validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check $platformi before submitting the form you would have to use javascript. because PHP will not get any thing in this variable before the form is submitted.